# Is it ethical for an employer to fire an employee who has criticized the company?

Tags: ethics

I understand in the United States it is perfectly legal for a company to fire employees who have made critical comments about the company. The 1st Amendment rights do not extend to employer/employee relations.

Legality aside, is it **ethical** for a company to fire an employee who is expressing his or her opinion in a respectful way (not whistleblowing)? Especially when considering that many companies have no compunctions about criticizing employees in performance evaluations, why is it often considered taboo for an employee to make a critical performance evaluation of his or her company?

Comment: Internally or externally? If I go to my boss and explain why things are all screwed up, I'm doing the company a service (as long as I also bring productive solutions). But if go to the press, not so much. I'll get fired.

Comment: What is a company? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood people.fire people. One can't ascribe morality to a thing with no brain. This is why allowing sovreign, or nearly sovreign companies, from the east india to google, is a pretty dumb thing for humanity to do.

Comment: @user4894 Let's say internal criticisms, either talking with a supervisor or say on an internal intranet forum.

Comment: @Richard More specifically, I'll ask if the HR Dept is behaving ethically.

Comment: It's impossible for an unethical, immoral economic system like the corporate state to ever get anything right.

Comment: Firing employees *who* have made critical comments is different from firing employees *for* making critical comments. The law does protect employee criticism in certain contexts (this is what NLRB is for), but it is complicated by the duty of loyalty, disclosing confidential information, and "upholding image of the company" considerations. In short, in this generality there is no definitive answer, see [Dysfunctional Disloyalty Standards in Employee Criticism Cases by Ristau](https://scholarlycommons.law.case.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1217&context=caselrev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must distinguish between **purpose of a company, local law, and personal motivations of management**.

For vast majority of companies primary purpose is simply profit. There are certain large companies (Google and  Disney for example) that use their position on the market to push certain political ideas (usually leftist and globalist) even if that hurts them economically, but they are in a minority.

As for the matter of law, most companies do try to obey letter of the law, at the same time trying to find loopholes that would help them with their primary purpose (i.e. profit) . In our case, as you said yourself, law does not protect employee.

Finally, we have personal motivations of the management, which includes ethics. Note that motivation of the management does not need to be aligned with the purpose of the company: for example manager A is criticized by employee B for his shortcomings, therefore manager A fires employee B to save his own skin. Manager A does not act in the interest of the company, he acts in his own interest.

Now we come to the main question, what is more important : **personal interest, interest of the company, or interest of the society as a whole**.

If you consider business world to be "dog eat dog" and "every man for himself", then firing employee who expressed view potentially harmful to the interest of some manager is justifiable. Of course, in such world nothing would stop that employee to try to return the favor as best he could.

If you consider interest of the company as most important (as we said, this usually means increasing profit as much as possible), then firing employee for his criticism could be justified only if such critique somehow harms the company. Since you excluded whistle-blowing (i.e. going outside with critique) this reduces potential damage therefore firing someone for his expressed opinion would be hard to ethically justify.

Finally, if you consider interest of the society as a whole as most important, it is virtually impossible to imagine opinion that would warrant firing, but not the punishment from that society itself. For example, certain countries criminalize certain ideas and expressing them could land you in jail (for example Holocaust denial) . But in that case law takes precedence over company laws, therefore it would not be ethical to fire someone because law already prescribes punishment.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Depends on point of view, but yes, they are considered leftist.

Comment: "It is virtually impossible to imagine opinion that would warrant firing, but not the punishment from that society itself". No, it is quite easy. If the employee uses obscenities and exaggerations in their criticism, from the point of view of society, it is protected speech, but, from the point of view of the company, it is a firing offense, because it reflects badly on them. This does happen in actual cases.

Comment: @Conifold Priorities, my friend. If society cherish obscene speech so much that it is protected, then company that values interest of society above everything else must also protect it. But since companies mostly care about themselves above everything else, they do not protect such speech in real life.

Comment: Wasn't disney himself a Nazi of sorts? If any company.represents the corporate right wing, it's Disney. Google aren't really a company, so much as a government department.

Comment: Protection does not imply cherishing, in the US it is done out of slippery slope, chilling effect on speech, etc., concerns. And prioritization does not need to line up the ethics of private and government action, there is no single "interest of society" to do so. It balances multiple ones, and private entities can have different balancing mixes than the one adopted for the legal system. So, even ideal companies can ethically fire people for doing things that the society exempts from punishment by the government.

Comment: @Richard Disney (company) now has owners with diametrically opposite views. And they are mostly pushing leftist and globalist ideology.

Comment: @Conifold You protect something that has value for you (i.e. you cherish it) . If society, as a whole, protects obscene speech, then that society, as a whole, cherishes such speech. Individuals or companies, of course, could have different opinions and interests then society as a whole. But if company chooses to strictly follow interests of society , that company simply could not mix anything -  obscene speech is protected, therefore it is protected.

Comment: You can define "cherish" way, but I find it question begging and out of step with the dictionaries (as in "cultivate with care and affection"). One can protect Y to uphold X, which is cherished, without cherishing Y at all, as a necessary evil. Strictly following the "interests" of society, or even a single individual, is impossible altogether. They clash on a regular basis, one has to be suppressed to advance another, and what gets advanced is not a principled decision, it is often pragmatic and context-dependent. Which is why we often judge X as right for someone else, but not us.